# React: Detect and wrap links in custom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linkify

Any help on this would be appreciated. I have blocks of text with links and have been using linkifyjs's React component to automatically wrap the links with anchor tags. However, now I would like to display a button next to each link with some custom behavior. Is there a way to wrap links in a custom component, say something like this?

```js
function CustomLink(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <a href={props.link}>{props.text}</>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

I know that I can pass in something like `tagName: 'strong'` in the options object, but it won't allow me to pass a custom React element. I get an error message if I try to do something like this (which works for built-in tags, like `'strong'`):

```js
// error => Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
// class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

function CustomLink(link) {
  console.log(link)
  return (
    <a href={link}>{link}</a>
  )
}

function TextWithLinks(props) {
  return (
    <Linkify className="d-inline" options={{tagName: CustomLink}}>
      {props.text}
    </Linkify>
  )
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `format` option and pass it a function.

```js
function CustomLink({link}) {
    return (
        <>
            <a href={link}>{link}</a>
            <button>Click Me</button>
        </>
    )
}

function TextWithLinks(props) {

    function formatter(value, type) {
        return <CustomLink link={value}/>
    }

    return (
        <Linkify className="d-inline" options={{tagName: 'div', format: formatter }}>
            {props.text}
        </Linkify>
    )
}
```

Comment: also you can pass the option `formatHref` a function that returns null. so you don't have a `href` on the wrapper